# .msg Module not being found

Tags: ros, rosrun, cmake, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. Here is my package and cmake file:

CMAKELIST:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(semantic_label_publisher)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)


## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   SemLabel.msg
#   Message2.msg
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
 )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES semantic_label_publisher
  CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

package.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>semantic_label_publisher</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The semantic_label_publisher package</description>


  <maintainer email="xxx@todo.todo">xxx</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>TODO</license>


  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->



  </export>
</package>
```

I built my package, did everything, but when I run

```
rosrun semantic_label_publisher semantic_label_publisher_node.py
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named semantic_label_publish.msg
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? If you need anymore info let me know.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261991/.msg-module-not-being-found/) by [Tex](https://answers.ros.org/users/30438/tex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-05-17**:
have you sourced the setup.bash for your workspace?

**Comment by [spooner-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/29765/spooner-dev/) on 2017-05-18**:
Yes, first check, that you didn't forget to source `devel/setup.bash`.
My guess would be, that you are trying to import in python by name `semantic_label_publish.msg` (as it says in the error), but your module has name - `semantic_label_publishER` (as it says in CMakeLists and package.xml)

**Comment by [Tex](https://answers.ros.org/users/30438/tex/) on 2017-05-18**:
@spooner-dev
I can't believe this! You're damn right, I am supposed to run semantic_label_publisher.

I am an idiot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest to try in your script to import:

```
from semantic_label_publisher.msg import SemLabel
```

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tex](https://answers.ros.org/users/30438/tex/) on 2017-05-18**:
Yeah, that's it. officially the largest idiot.